# Speeding up agg on large pandas table

Tags: python, pandas

Here's the input and desired output

```
input
   id  elapsed            state  rub      action
0  a1        0        (1, 2, 3)  500  (3, 65, 2)
1  a1       10         (15, 19)   20          ()
2  a1      100             (1,)    1        (1,)
3  a2        0           (3, 4)  100   (3, 2, 9)
4  a2       34  (5, 6, 7, 8, 9)    3        (5,)

output
   id       elapsed                        state           rub      action
0  a1          (0,)                 ((1, 2, 3),)        (500,)  (3, 65, 2)
1  a1       (0, 10)        ((1, 2, 3), (15, 19))     (500, 20)          ()
2  a1  (0, 10, 100)  ((1, 2, 3), (15, 19), (1,))  (500, 20, 1)        (1,)
3  a2          (0,)                    ((3, 4),)        (100,)   (3, 2, 9)
4  a2       (0, 34)    ((3, 4), (5, 6, 7, 8, 9))      (100, 3)        (5,)
```

Here's my code.

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame(dict(id=['a1','a1','a1','a2','a2'], elapsed=[0,10,100,0,34]
                    , state=[(1,2,3),(15,19),(1,),(3,4),(5,6,7,8,9)], rub=[500,20,1,100,3]
                    , action=[(3,65,2),(),(1,),(3,2,9,),(5,)]))
print(df1)

def stack_df(in_df):
    def stack(block):
        out = list()
        for n in range(1,block.shape[0]+1):
            part = block[block["nframes"]<=n].iloc[:,:-2]
            df = part.groupby("id").agg(tuple).reset_index()
            out.append(df)
        
        out = pd.concat(out, axis=0, ignore_index=True)
        out.insert(out.shape[1], "action", block["action"].values)
        
        return out
    
    out_df = in_df.groupby("id").apply(stack).reset_index(drop=True)
    
    return out_df


df1.sort_values(["id","elapsed"], inplace=True, ignore_index=True)
df1["nframes"] = df1.groupby(["id"]).cumcount()+1
df2 = stack_df(df1)
print(df2)
```

This takes multiple hours to run when the number of ids is 100,000+.  I realize this problem is embarrassingly parallelizable and using `multiprocessing.pool.apply_async` get perfect parallelization with 12 cores.  I was wondering if it was possible to speed up the inner stack function as such.  It seems that there should be a better way than using the loop there.